# How to create a popup window login upon a button click on a webpage?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, popup, windows-authentication

I have a website created based on windows authentication using C#.
Upon a button submit, I need to have a popup windows login to get the user's credentials before can proceed.

So on this case, the parent page still retains the original user A credentials.
The popup windows login can have another user's credentials captured and passed to the parent form.

How do I do that?

Comment: This seems like a dangerous way to do things. Why does the site need the *Windows* credentials of a different user? Is there perhaps some other way you could design this?

Comment: this is needed if the webpage is for sales person to capture sales. If a void/refund is needed, upon click of the button the window popup will ask for a supervisor authentication (which is another person). So the void/refund record captured will have the approved value of the supervisor.